# Icons in HTML and CSS as a code (eg: &#xe348;)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, icons

I participate on a project where are displayed icons like this:

```
<span class="streamline" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe006;">Some label</span>
```

The project is in Ruby on Rails, so I thought that the icons will be saved in the `/assets` folder, but they're not there.

In the CSS files, I see only this:

```
.streamline[data-icon]:after, .filtericons[data-icon]:before, .slicons {
  font-family: 'streamline';
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

How does the icons works? I would need to add a new icon, but I am not sure at all how the system of displaying icons working - it's a thing of CSS?

THank you

Comment: Those icons are font-based sprites, so in order to add a new icon you need to change `data-icon` code also all the icons will be in one file. You need to find the codes for the other icons. Check this [link](https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7/issues/1).

Answer (score 0):

The `data-icon` is referencing a character within the icon font `streamline`.  Look for something this at the top of your stylesheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: streamline;
    src: url( /* url to .eot file */ ) format("embedded-opentype"),
         url( /* url to .woff file */ ) format("woff"),
         url( /* url to .tff file */ ) format("truetype"),
         url( /* url to .svg file */ ) format("svg");
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

That CSS defines the `font-family` `streamline`. The URL's to the font files will show you where they're located.

If you want to see what icons are available in that font, you can download the .tff file and try this:

[MyFonts - How do I see all the characters in a font?](http://www.myfonts.com/Article8099.html)

To use a different icon that exists in the font you're using, you will just need to change the `data-icon` attribute to the corresponding html entity (`&#*****;`).  To get this code, copy the character from your font that you want to use, and paste it into the 'Decoded' box on this page:

[HTML entity encoder/decoder](http://mothereff.in/html-entities)

To use icons that don't exist in `streamline` you will need to replace the font files with new ones that include the characters you want.